# Argument 'MasterController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm trying to get one of my pages in my app to display some data, but I keep getting "Argument 'MasterController' is not a function, got undefined." The strange thing is that I isolated the code out of the files and it runs perfectly by itself, but the moment I put it back, it doesn't work anymore.

I simply want the app to load the transactions data when the "Old Baskets" menu item is clicked.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's driving me insane!!!

This is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <title>Laundri</title>  

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css"/>

  <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>    

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
  </script>
  <script>
    var transactionsmodule = angular.module('transactions', ['onsen']);
  </script>
  <script>
    ons.ready(function() {
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .page--menu-page__background {
      background-color: #333;
    }

    .page--menu-page__content {
      color: white;
    }

    .menu-close,
    .menu-close > .toolbar-button {
      color: #999;
    }

    .menu-list,
    .menu-item:first-child,
    .menu-item:last-child,
    .menu-item {
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: none !important;
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .menu-item {
      padding: 0 0 0 20px;
      line-height: 52px;
      height: 52px;
      text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 0px;
    }

    .menu-item:active {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    .menu-notification {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 12px;
      font-size: 14px;
      height: 16px;
      line-height: 16px;
      min-width: 16px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .bottom-menu-list,
    .bottom-menu-item:first-child,
    .bottom-menu-item:last-child,
    .bottom-menu-item {
      border-color: #393939;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: none !important;
      color: #ccc;
    }

    .bottom-menu-item:active {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>    
  <!-- SLIDING MENU -->
  <ons-sliding-menu
    menu-page="menu.html" main-page="home.html" side="left"
    var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true">
  </ons-sliding-menu>

  <ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
      <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent"></ons-toolbar>

      <ons-list class="menu-list">
        <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('home.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-home"></ons-icon>
          Home
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('newbasket.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-plus"></ons-icon>
          New Laundry Basket
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('oldbasket.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-history"></ons-icon>
          Old Baskets
          <div class="notification menu-notification">3</div>
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>

      <br>

      <ons-list class="bottom-menu-list">
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page3.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          Settings
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page4.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          Help
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page5.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          Send feedback
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="home.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Home</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-row style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <ons-col align="center">
          <i style="font-size: 10em;" class="ion-tshirt-outline"></i>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>

    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="newbasket.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          New Laundry Basket
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div ng-app="store" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
      <ons-row style="margin-top: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px;">
        <ons-row style="margin-bottom: 4em;">
          <ons-col align="left" width="10%">
            <button class="button button--outline" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; height: 235px;" ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">&uarr;</button>
          </ons-col>
          <ons-col align="center" width="80%">
            <img style="max-width:200px;" class="item_image" ng-src="{{store.currentProduct.images}}"/>
          </ons-col>
          <ons-col align="right" width="10%">
            <button class="button button--outline" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; height: 235px;" ng-click="count = count - 1" ng-init="count=0">&darr;</button>
          </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row style="margin-bottom:20px;">
          <ons-col align="center">
            <center><input type="number" class="text-input" min="0" max="100" value="{{count}}" style="text-align: center;"></input><center>
          </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row style="margin-top:2em;">
          <ons-col align="center">
            <ons-button modifier="cta">Add to basket</ons-button>
          </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
          <ons-button modifier="outline" style="position: absolute;bottom: 10px;left: 10px;" ng-click="store.prevProduct()">Back</ons-button>
          <ons-button modifier="outline" style="position: absolute;bottom: 10px;right: 10px;" ng-click="store.nextProduct()">Next</ons-button>
      </ons-row>
      </div>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="oldbasket.html">

    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-app="app" ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Old Baskets</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div ng-app="transactions">
      <ons-list ng-controller="MasterController">
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item" ng-repeat="transaction in transactions">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">{{transaction.title}}</span>
                <span class="item-label">{{transaction.label}}</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">{{transaction.desc}}</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
      </div>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="page3.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Settings</div>
      </ons-toolbar>


      <ons-row style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <ons-col align="center">
          <ul class="list">
            <li class="list__item">
              Setting 1
              <label class="switch switch--list-item">
                <input type="checkbox" class="switch__input" checked>
                <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
              Setting 2
              <label class="switch switch--list-item">
                <input type="checkbox" class="switch__input">
                <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
              Setting 3
              <label class="switch switch--list-item">
                <input type="checkbox" class="switch__input" checked>
                <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
              Setting 4
              <label class="switch switch--list-item">
                <input type="checkbox" class="switch__input">
                <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>

    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="page4.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Help</div>
      </ons-toolbar>


      <ons-row style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <ons-col align="center">
          <ons-button modifier="light" ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
            HELP ME!
          </ons-button>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>

    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="page5.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Feedback</div>
      </ons-toolbar>


      <ons-row style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <ons-col align="center">
          <ons-button modifier="light" ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
            WADDAYATHINK?
          </ons-button>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>

    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>


</body>
</html>
```

And this is the app.js:

```
(function() {

  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    var productIndex = 0;
    this.currentProduct = items[productIndex];
    this.nextProduct = function() {
      productIndex = productIndex+1;
      this.currentProduct = items[productIndex];
    };
    this.prevProduct = function() {
      productIndex = productIndex-1;
      this.currentProduct = items[productIndex];
    };

  });

  var items = [
    { item: 'Top', number: 2, images: 'img/shirt_icon.jpeg', description: 'T-shirts, undershirts, singlets, etc.' },
    { item: 'Bottom', number: 5, images: 'img/pants_icon.jpg', description: 'Jeans, shorts, pants, etc.' },
    { item: 'Underwear', number: 3, images: 'img/underwear_icon.jpg', description: 'Undies, G-strings, etc.' },
  ];

  var transactionsmodule = angular.module('transactions', ['onsen']);

  transactionsmodule.controller('MasterController', function($scope, $data) {
    $scope.transactions = $data.transactions;  
  });

  transactionsmodule.factory('$data', function() {
      var data = {};

      data.transactions = [
          { 
              title: 'Item 1 Title',
              label: '4h',
              desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
          },
          { 
              title: 'Another Item Title',
              label: '6h',
              desc: 'Ut enim ad minim veniam.'
          },
          { 
              title: 'Yet Another Item Title',
              label: '1day ago',
              desc: 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'
          },
          { 
              title: 'Yet Another Item Title',
              label: '1day ago',
              desc: 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'
          }
      ]; 

      return data;
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You called this twice.

```
var transactionsmodule = angular.module('transactions', ['onsen']);
```

One from the scripts tags and one in the app.js.
This creates two instances of your module. If you want to get the reference to the original one use the syntax:

```
   var transactionsmodule = angular.module('transactions');
```

Comment: Hmmm, I removed the instance within the script tags but the problem is still there - the oldbasket.html page loads but it's blank with the same "Argument 'MasterController' is not a function, got undefined" problem.

Comment: The reason why it's hard to point out the problem is because you're not following best practices in the way you declare almost everything. I recommend going to angularjs guide and follow it step per step. In any case I just found out that you declared ng-app several times. If you want to use another module, just add it as a dependency to your main ng-app.